# Variable defined inside conditional not available outside

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements, typeof

I know this is super basic but I cannot figure out why it is not working. I was expecting to see the element .basic_form logged in the last console.log. Instead I get the following:

```js
if ( typeof basic_form === 'undefined' || basic_form === nulll ){
        console.log( 'not defined yet' );
        let basic_form = document.querySelector( '.basic_form' );
        console.log( basic_form) ;
    }
    console.log( basic_form );

Output:
1> not defined yet
2> the element .basic_form
3> Uncaught ReferenceError: basic_form is not defined (???)
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `let` (and `const`) are block scoped. `{...}` creates a block here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable declared inside block are not accessible outside. You can find more on this [Variable scope and closure](https://javascript.info/closure).

Answer (score 0):

basic_form it's defined inside the if statement you need to define it outside.
I think it should be like this.

```js
let basic_form = document.querySelector( '.basic_form' );

if ( typeof basic_form === 'undefined' || basic_form === nulll ){
        console.log( 'not defined yet' );
        console.log( basic_form) ;
    }
console.log( basic_form );
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. And although, this would be a different question, my issue is that these pages are ajax loaded, and can be loaded multiple times, so doing it this way, I  get another error, saying the variable has been already defined.